# GridBagLayout Coordinates Confusion

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

Hello   i am beginner in jav  and   coding  Address Book in Java ,  for that i am using  GridBagLayout . see attached image   for  `JTextArea`  coordinates are `gridx=0` ; `gridy=0`  and for `JButton1`    `gridx=1;` and `gridy=0;` but  i am confused for `Jbutton2`  as i did try `gridx=1` and `gridy=1` but  (did try other sol as well )  but that is not plotted in right place as shown in image attached ..  please can someone clarify me this  i am really stuck  int it !i did  this picrue in  paint  to show what i am trying to do ,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridBagLayout isn't that friendly when you are just beginning to learn about layout managers. You should start with simpler layout managers such as BoxLayout or even GridLayout.

Here's [an excellent visual comparison of layout managers and what they do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) .

For example, you can use a BoxLayout (Vertical) for your JFrame and first divide up your JFrame into 2 JPanels. We'll call these 2 JPanel's `top` and `bottom`:

- `top` can hold the JTextArea, JButton1,2,3

  - `top` itself can use a BoxLayout (Horizontal) to manage / hold 2 JPanels within itself: `top_left` and `top_right`
  - `top_left` can hold the JTextArea, and not need a layout manager since it has a single element.
  - `top_right` can hold JButtons 1-3, and again use a BoxLayout (Vertical)
- `bottom` can hold JButton4,5 and JTextField

Hopefully this is enough to show you the hierarchical idea of how a Java GUI is decomposed.

Comment: yes it really seems  tricky to work with GridBagLayout , which one should  i use Gridlayout or box , please guide  and Thanks

Comment: @SikanderNawaz I'd start with BoxLayout just because it's a simpler idea. After you get the hang of it you can try GridLayout, which is much more customizable.